Single characters detection/recognition.Deleting of the special characters from image
I have an image which is look like this: enter image description here
Reserve link: https://ibb.co/HVd9g3D
And I want to delete all special characters from it to make it look like this: enter image description here
Reserve link: https://ibb.co/mz7Wqgg
To achieve this i  get coordinates and confidence score of each character on the image. After that, if confidence of a charater is low in compare with others i paint it over.I use pytesseract.Here is the result of pytesseract programm for image from above.
Character: M, Confidence: 3
Character: O, Confidence: 33
Character: ’, Confidence: 66
Character: 8, Confidence: 77
Character: 5, Confidence: 97
Character: ‘, Confidence: 121
Character: 9, Confidence: 131
Character: 1, Confidence: 154
Character: @, Confidence: 185
Unfortunatelly, even for this ideal image confidence score for special symbol ''e3 in a circle'' recognized as a @ is highest.
Could you advice me better programm which can detect single characters on image with their coordinates and confidence scores ?Or maybe there is other way to delete special charaters from image ?The main problem is that i dont know the full list of special charaters, because it is almost infinite.I just know that special character is something different from ordinary numbers and english characters and cant be recognized correctly by any OCR.
My code:
import cv2
import pytesseract
import os

# Path to Tesseract executable (change this path based on your installation)
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

# Read the input image
img_path = 'crop/14/image_4.png'
img = cv2.imread(img_path)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Perform OCR to detect characters and obtain the result with bounding boxes
custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6 -l eng'  # OCR engine mode, page segmentation mode, and language set to English
results = pytesseract.image_to_boxes(gray, config=custom_config)

# Create a folder to save the cropped images
output_folder = 'cropped_images'
os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)

# Draw bounding boxes around the detected characters and save the cropped parts of the image
for result in results.splitlines():
    result = result.split(' ')
    character = result[0]
    confidence = result[1]
    #print(f"Character: {character}, Confidence: {int(confidence)/10}")
    print(f"Character: {character}, Confidence: {confidence}")
    x, y, w, h = int(result[1]), int(result[2]), int(result[3]), int(result[4])
    cropped_img = img[img.shape[0] - h:img.shape[0] - y, x:w]
    
    # Save the cropped image in the output folder
    output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, f'cropped_{character}.png')
    cv2.imwrite(output_path, cropped_img)

    # Draw bounding boxes on the original image
    #img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, img.shape[0] - y), (w, img.shape[0] - h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

# Display the original image with bounding boxes
#cv2.imshow('Image with Bounding Boxes', img)
#cv2.waitKey(0)
#cv2.destroyAllWindows()


Add image in your question because we're not supposed to open external link

Unfortunatelly i can apload images only like this because of the reputation score on stack overflow.I will try to reupload it.

I added 2 reserve links with images. It should be possible to check them now.

if you are comfortable with LSTM models I think it would be better to achieve this kind of task.

Is LSTM program/ model for this or simple task exist?Could you give me some examples, please, like names of such model, links on some project like this, etc ?
